# how to import a standalone module build with browserify?

Tags: javascript, browserify

My question is how do I achieve importing a standalone module obtained with browserify, inside another javascript file. Here are some specific details:

I created a standalone module with browserify like this:

```
browserify module.js --s module_name > output.js
```

The file module.js contains at the end the line

```
module.exports = module_name;
```

Inside a file "use_module.js", I can now use the module `module_name`, with this code in some html file:

```
<sctipt src="output.js">
<sctipt src="use_module.js">
```

But what I would like is to specify just the script "use_module.js" in my html file, and somehow import "output.js" inside "use_module.js" directly in the javascript code. I tried two different approaches :

- I tried javascript `import module_name from './output.js'` inside use_module.js, but then it cannot find the module `module_name`. Somehow I'm not sure `module.exports` is the same as `export`, neither with what browserify does with my `module.exports` anyway. (I'm very confused about all that).
- I tried with `require(./output.js)` and then re-using browserify, but I then get a lot of weird errors with browserify, about tons of missing modules. Maybe I should specify some module informations in a file next to "output.js", that browserify can process, but I don't know really.

Comment: Isn't this what `--external` does?

Comment: you mean as a browserify option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood what was failing in both approaches :

- As I thought, `import` works only with `export` and not `modules.exports`. Also I read that browserify cannot work with the `import/export` syntax which is still too new.
- More interestingly : a browserified file contains plenty of `require(...)` calls, which refers to a function created by browserify, and not to the CommonJS `require` keyword. Of course browserify does not know the difference, and thus look for tons a module to import a second time. All that needs to be done is to rename the word "require" into something else, and browserify can be applied a second time...

I however do not find my answer completely satisfactory : there must be a proper way to do this...